# signalR calls a server method and that method calls a callback method ,outside the hub. How can I call client function from that method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I want to process a stream of data and need to display the processed data near real time. For that I created a hub class

```
    public class AzureGuidanceEventHubReceiver : Hub
      {
        EventProcessorHost eventProcessorHost;
        public async void ProcessEvents()
         {
           //Do some code here
           eventProcessorHost.RegisterEventProcessorAsync<SimpleEventProcessor>();
         }
      }
```

And the class which processes the data is,

```
     public class SimpleEventProcessor : IEventProcessor
      {

        public async Task ProcessEventsAsync(PartitionContext context, IEnumerable<EventData> events)
           {
            foreach (EventData eventData in events)
             {
                int data;
                var newData = this.DeserializeEventData(eventData);
                //how to display newData in the browser????????????????????????????????                                                
             }
     }
```

My client side code is

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var receiverHub= $.connection.azureGuidanceEventHubReceiver;
        receiverHub.client.displayMessage = function (data) {
        var encodedData = $('<div />').text(data).html();
        // Add the message to the page. 
            $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + encodedData + '</li>');
        };

        //// Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

                $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                receiverHub.server.processEvents();
            });
        });
    });
```

Here I made a call to ProcessEvents method in the Hub class and that registers the SimpleEventProcessor. And thus execution comes into ProcessEventsAsync in SimpleEventProcessor. From this ProcessEventsAsync method, I need to call the clientside code to display the data. Do I need to make SimpleEventProcessor also as a hub class?

Comment: You have to add a method / function on the client , that receives the call from the server  take a look at this article and scroll down to "How to create and use Hub classes"  http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server

Comment: I already have a method named "DisplayMessage". But I need to call this method from the SimpleEventProcessor class which is not a hub class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following code to get hold of HubContext which allows you to invoke client methods from outside of hub istance:

```
var hubContext =  GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<AzureGuidanceEventHubReceiver>();
hubContext.Clients.All.displayMessage(dataToDisplay);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I am facing a problem that The client method DisplayMessage is not executing everytime. I need to display a stream of message.  But when I put debugger in the client code, it executes everytime.Here is my client code.

```
    chat.client.displayMessage = function (data) {                
            // Html encode display data 

            debugger;

            var encodedData = $('<div />').text(data.GPSPosition).html();
            var data = encodedData.split("\n");
            var varlat = data[0].replace("Latitude:","").trim();
            var varlong = data[1].replace("Longitude:", "").trim();
            ShowInGoogleMap(varlat, varlong);
          };
```

how can i display a stream of messages? Why it is only working with debugger?

Comment: help me understand this ,i also have this problem. using web api 2 project for services and mvc 5 project as client app,my hub is at web api now i want to call a hub method from client application. #1. i am not able to generate automatic proxy probably because of separate projects. #2. if i use without generated proxy method ,server method dosent gets called , i get error at console log that ,error calling server method.